# Regex to find sentence which has no html tag in a article and the sentence will be wrapped by html paragraph tag.How to do it?

Tags: php, regex

I have a article which has content on it . I want to find the sentence which has no html tags and then wrap it by html paragraph tag.
code are given below-

```html
<p>line 1 </p>
line 2 
<p> line 3 </p>
line 4 
<p> line 5 </p>
line 6
```

But i want the output like this-

```html
<p>line 1 </p>
<p>line 2 </p>
<p>line 3 </p>
<p>line 4 </p>
<p>line 5 </p>
<p>line 6 </p>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely, the answer contains *"... but use a parser instead ..."* somewhere. What have you come up with so far?

Comment: I have a website and it has feeds that feeds come to facebook instant articles. Sometime in facebook instant articles there are some text which has no p tag and that line go hidden as the text has no p tag on it. thanks for ur interest @Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't parse HTML with regex.
But in case you absolutely want to, here is one.

The following regex will select lines that doesn't use tags as stated:

```
^(?!<p>).*(?!<\/p>)
```

You can the replace the match with:

```
<p>$0</p>
```

[See the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/siaKsm/1)

Here is an example:

```
$re = '/^(?!<p>).*(?!<\/p>)/m';
$str = '<p>line 1 </p>
line 2 unwrapped
<p> line 3 </p>
line 4 unwrapped
<p> line 5 </p>
line 6 unwrapped';
$subst = '<p>$0</p>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Fill in some spaces and see [**how your regex fails**](https://regex101.com/r/siaKsm/2) - use don't use regular expressions on a DOM at all.

Comment: @Jan I agree. But I answered the OP's question with the provided input. Spaces are not part of it.